# [UIImageView setScrollSpeed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

Here I need to once I click blue dot imageview.Leftside scrollView
should start to scrolling.
Below I added the code that I used my TableViewCell

```
MyMedsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyMedsTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.autoScrolling.hidden = NO;

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapping:)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[cell.threedot setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[cell.threedot addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

Here I added the header file of my TableViewCell

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CustomView.h"
#import <AutoScrollLabel/CBAutoScrollLabel.h>

@interface MyMedsTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet CBAutoScrollLabel *autoScroll;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *threedot;
```

Below I added the method that I used to call cell property after a click imageview

```
-(void)singleTapping:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    CBAutoScrollLabel *autoScroll = (CBAutoScrollLabel*)recognizer.view;
    autoScroll.scrollSpeed = 30;
    NSLog(@"image clicked");
}
```

Here I added my error log

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView setScrollSpeed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe274cac530'

I tried different ways but still, I got this error. Can someone help for this?

Comment: why is your variable called `imageView` if you specify its type to be `CBAutoScrollLabel`. In fact it *is* an `UIImageView` which does not have a method `setScrollSpeed:`.

Comment: where do you add `singleTap` to any view?

Comment: @luk2302 edited mate.
[cell.autoScrolling addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

Comment: Please stop defacing this question and asking something different than was originally asked. If you *really* feel like you need more help write down a new question and state clearly what you want to achieve.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52644006/how-to-access-table-cell-after-clicking-uiimageview-in-uitableviewcell-objecti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding your UITapGestureRecognizer to UIImageView

```
[cell.threedot addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

You should be adding it to your CBAutoScrollLabel

```
[cell.autoScroll addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

Comment: Hi Nishith,
My fault, that uses lousy variable names for this. I corrected those now. can you see it above.

Comment: @RajithaPerera See still you are adding your gesture recognizer to your image view i.e. threeDot and in singleTapping you are trying to downcast it to CBAutoScrollLabel using CBAutoScrollLabel *autoScroll = (CBAutoScrollLabel*)recognizer.view. But your recognizer.view is threeDot that is an UIImageView not CBAutoScrollLabel

Comment: Ah Ok, Nishith.So above I added an image. Can you tell me know how can I start scroll view once I click blue dots?

Comment: That is an entirely different issue, dont ask two unrelated question in one post. Your crash is solved, accept this answer please.

Comment: Can you suggest a solution for that?