# How to access table cell after clicking UiImageView in UITableViewCell - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

**Below I added the code that I used my TableViewCell**

```
MyMedsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyMedsTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.autoScrolling.hidden = NO;

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapping:)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[cell.autoScrolling setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[cell.autoScrolling addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

**Here I added the header file of my TableViewCell**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CustomView.h"
#import <AutoScrollLabel/CBAutoScrollLabel.h>

@interface MyMedsTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet CBAutoScrollLabel *autoScroll;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *autoScrolling;
```

**Below I added the method that I used to call cell property after a click imageview**

```
-(void)singleTapping:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"image clicked");
}
```

I tried different ways but still could not. Can someone help for this?

Comment: is `userInteraction` of `UIImageview`` is enabled??

Comment: You could use tags if your tableView isn't that complex.

Comment: @Larme how can I pass tag to a method and how can I access cell properties using tag

Comment: @Dimple  method is calling when I click

Comment: You need to explain what you want to do at the end, because it can change the method, and also how many sections/row you have.

Comment: Here I have a blue color dot imageView. So once I click it there is a scroll Lebel in the left side. So It needs to start scroll. numbers rows can be dynamic

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding you have problem to detect a tap in three blue dotted imageView in your header.

So the solution is to use a UIButton instead of that UIImageView in your header set three blue dotted image for button image property.

in your cellForRowAt use

```
cell.myButton.tag = indexPath.row;
```

Now add a action for this button in your viewController class.

```
- (IBAction)myButton:(UIButton *)sender {

    // Here you can identify button by its tag value
    NSLog(@"Button %ld tapped", (long)sender.tag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Using UIBUtton insteaf of UIImageView is better option.

2) If you cant go with 1) and must use UIImageview, You can access cell using following:

first assign Tag of Imageview to Indexpath.row.

```
cell.autoScrolling.tag = indexPath.row;
```

You can use this tag in tapgesturerecogniser method.

```
    -(void)singleTapping:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
          UIImageView *autoScrolling = (UIImageView *)[recognizer view];
          long  tag = autoScrolling.tag;
         NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:tag  inSection:0];
           MyMedsTableViewCell *cell = (MyMedsTableViewCell *)[tblRegister cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //You can access property of cell now. 
 }
```